# SELECT data by foreign key. MySQL

Tags: mysql

Please advise me how to query below correctly.
I have two tables: parents and children.

```
children (child_id, parent_id_fk, name, surname, ...)
parents  (parent_id, name, surname, phone number, ...)
```

I struggle to get the right SELECT, which will give me the children data + parent data who is assigned to the child. Should the assignment be done as above or should I create another table, which will associate the parent with child, for example

```
child_has_parent(key_id, child_id_fk, parent_id_fk)?
```

Comment: The thing you are looking for is called `JOIN`.

Comment: The parents-children relation is already there, in the childen table.

Comment: The correct way to declare your tables depends of your parent-children relation : does the children have 1 parent or can it have multiples parents ? Same question goes the parent.

Comment: I am interested only in children, so in this case children has 1:n relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table have already therelationship chidren parent trough its foreign key

So

```
SELECT 
  c.name, c.surname,
 p.name, p.surname, p.phone number
FROM 
  children c INNER JOIN parents p ON c.parent_id_fk = p.parent_id
```

But of course you can also use your relationship table for it

```
SELECT
  c.name, c.surname,
  p.name, p.surname, p.phone number
FROM child_has_parent chp
INNER JOIN  children c  ON chp.child_id_fk = c.child_id
INNER JOIN  parents p ON chp.parent_id_fk = p.parent_id
```

This should give you the same result

Of course when you have children without parents, you have to LEFT JOIN parents p.

Also to get both parents in one row. it gets a bit more complicated and for that you should provide example data